# Writing Maven Dependency for javax.persistence

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, maven, persistence

Can someone help me write the dependency for `javax.persistence`. I have googled it but nothing worked.

I [bumped into this page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-coping-with-sun-jars.html) that gives some details on how to write the dependency, but yet i am unable to write it. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is the one for `javax.persistence`:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and this is for the whole Java EE 6 stack:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
   <version>6.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Edit**
Note that I specified a `provided` scope here, which means that your dependency is available at compile- and test-time, but will not be packaged into your artifacts. This is usually needed if you want to deploy your artifacts in an application server, since they provide their own implementation of the api.

Comment: So you recommend that i use the 2nd option

Comment: Yes, if you would like to use other features of the JEE stack - like EJB or Servlets for example. If you are only interested in persistence, use the first one. :)

Comment: Thanks! But I am interesting how one could find the answer by himself? Without copypasting from Google/SO...

Answer (score 5):

And add this dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

That "Coping with Sun JARs" page might be a little outdated, this JAR is available in the [Maven Central Repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/persistence/persistence-api/)

Answer (score 1):

Updated link:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2 is here.

and the maven dependency is as below:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: This does not works for me.

Comment: @dgupta3091 what's the error you are facing now?

Answer (score 0):

For the latest versions `javax.persistance` is not working instead of that we can use `jakarta.persistence` to create an entity or resolve the error *Cannot resolve symbol 'Entity'*. For that need to add the dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: i can get neither jakarta.persistence.* nor javax.persistence.* working.

Somebody keeps playing musical chairs with this library.  I understand "javax" had to be dropped due to Oracle trademark.  But, the latest versions of jakarta.persistence-api don't have what I need.